# On permutations and Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

$mn$ squares of equal size are arranged to forma a rectangle of dimension $m$ by $n$, where $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers.

Two squares will be called 'neighbours' if they have exactly one common side. A natural number is written in each square such that the number written in any square is the arithmetic mean of the numbers written in its neighbouring squares.

> Show that this is possible only if the numbers used are equal.

I am not able to start an analytical approach to this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $m$ be the least number on the board. If the numbers aren't all equal, there must be a square containing $m$ and having a neighbor with a different number. The rest is easy.